# How do you set ContentPresenter properties inside a GridViewRowPresenter?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to get the text inside my ListView to align to the top of the cells.

This is what I've done so far:

The data is bound like this:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Width="50">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
                                    Converter={StaticResource lviIndexToString}}"
                     Foreground="White"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="80">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LogTime}"
                     Foreground="{StaticResource ConsoleOrange}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="80">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageType}"
                     Foreground="{Binding MessageType,
                         Converter={StaticResource logMsgToColor}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

the `ItemContainer` is styled like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Grid>
        <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          <GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
              <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
          </GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>
        </GridViewRowPresenter>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

It works if the ContentPresenters VerticalAlignment is set to 'Stretch'. However, the visual tree reveals that the ContentPresenter style is being overridden by something, but I can't for the life of me figure out by what.
[image]

If anyone have any idea how to set the nested ContentPresenters properties, or educate me in how to set up a custom GridViewRowPresenter to have more control over how to display the data, I would be most greatful.

I apologise if this has been answered elsewhere, but my google-fu search (and the search here) have not revealed any useful solutions.

**Update**
The end goal is to align the text in the first 3 columns to the top of the ListViewItem.
[image]

Comment: What u want, try to explain in simple words, or with an image.

Comment: I want to set the ContentPresenters VerticalAlignment to Stretch inside the GridViewRowPresenter

Comment: I am asking actual requirement in ur listview.

Comment: Oh. Well, what I need is to have 4 columns. The 4th column can be multi-line. And when that happens, I want the text in the other 3 columns to align to the top. 
I have tried using ListView.ItemTemplate instead, however, that slows down the whole process insanely, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To override value of `VerticalAlignment` property `ContentPresenter`, we need to set it with some higher precedence step. Animation holds number 2 position in [precedence order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3).

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalAlignment">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <VerticalAlignment>Top</VerticalAlignment>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Another approach is just to handle `ContentPresenter.Loaded` event and set property values there.

```
  <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
         <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ContentPresenter_Loaded"/>
  </Style>
```

Handler :

```
void ContentPresenter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ContentPresenter).VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
}
```

This changing of property using `Loaded` event handler can be done using `Blend Behaviors / Attached Property` too.

Comment: @andidegn Thanks, try to post relevant to-the-point description of your problem in your question. This helps.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought I did by writing:
"I am trying to get the text inside my ListView to align to the top of the cells."
and
"If anyone have any idea how to set the nested ContentPresenters properties..."